# Entire row is not getting selected in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am trying to select an entire row from the jtable. The first time, entire row is getting selected, but from the next time, only few cells are getting selected though entire row data is obtained.

Code:

```
        jDelete.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(!jtable.getSelectionModel().getValueIsAdjusting())
                deleteRow(jtable.getSelectedRow());

        }
    });

jtable.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
            if(!e.getValueIsAdjusting()){
                jtable.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
                String[] arr = new String[9];
                int row = jtable.getSelectedRow();
                if(row!=-1){
                for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
                    arr[i] = (String) jtable.getValueAt(row, i);
                }
                jId.setText(arr[0]);
                jName.setText(arr[1]);
                jTime.setSelectedItem(arr[2]);
                jMail.setText(arr[3]);
                jMobile.setText(arr[4]);
                jCourse.setSelectedItem(arr[5]);
                jFee.setText(arr[6]);
                jPaid.setText(arr[7]);
                jBalance.setText(arr[8]);
            }
            }
        }
    });
```

When I try to select the row and delete it, first time it is deleting properly. From the next time, when I click on a row, few cells are shown as selected but the entire row is obtained. How to make it to display as the entire row selected?

The first time : The entire is row selected properly.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

The second time : The entire row is not selected entirely.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

The entire code is posted here :

https://ideone.com/7EJiRQ

Comment: Post a proper [mcve[ that demonstrates the problem. We don't know the context of the above code is used and can only make guesses.

Comment: Do I have to post entire code? I just added images of the output. Please check whether you can get any idea about this.

Comment: The problem is with your code. Posting an image tell us nothing about the code. `Do I have to post entire code?` - Sorry I forgot to include the link. Post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. As I said below, the default behaviour is to highlight the entire row on selection. I gave some suggestions what the problem may be. Otherwise you need to isolate the problem. You do this by creating a simple example.

Comment: So create a frame with a Jtable with 3 rows of data. Does the selection work? I'll bet yes, So the you add a button to delete the selected row. Does it work? Again, I'll bet it does. When it stops working then you know what you changed and can attempt to fix the problem or post the code showing us the problem. The point of the MCVE is to simplify the problem to help YOU debug the code yourself.

Comment: Thank you. I have added the entire code and gave the link here. Please check that.

Comment: 1) The code should be included in the forum 2) You were not asked for your entire code. We are not here to debug your entire program. You question was about a table with a Delete button. So you need to create a simple JTable with a few rows of data and then add a "Delete" button to delete the selected row. The whole code should be about 20-30 lines of code because that is all that is required to test deleting a row of data from the table model. Once that works, then you start adding in the functionality for your other buttons. We don't have time to look at 200 lines of code.

Comment: Sorry for that, I am new to this. I didn't get how to do that.SO I posted the entire code.

Comment: `I didn't get how to do that.` - I explained how to do that. Here is an example of an MCVE that does exactly what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37550007/131872. 1) the code is posted in the forum. 2) it is a simple JFrame with a JTable and a JButton to delete seleted row(s). So start with that code as a simple MCVE. 1) remove the JList logic 2) add multiple columns to the table. Does it still work? 3) then add a ListSelectionListener. Does it still work. By making one change at a time you isolate  where your problem is. This is basic debugging.

Answer (score 0):

```
jtable.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
```

Don't set this property in the selection listener. This is the default behaviour when the table is created. So the above code is not needed.

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(!jtable.getSelectionModel().getValueIsAdjusting())
            deleteRow(jtable.getSelectedRow());
```

Why are you checking the selection model in the ActionListener. There is no need to do this. The row will already be selected when the button is clicked.

However the code should be something like:

```
int row = jtable.getSelectedRow();
if (row != -1)
    deleteRow( row );
```

This will make sure a row is selected before attempting to delete it.